# What are your favorite lesser-known LyX tips and tricks?

Tags: lyx

Things that you have learnt from experience which might help others.

Comment: This might solicit primarily opinion-based answers (leading to possible closure of the post). You need to be specific in your request, and this is very general.

Comment: First tip: Don't use `lyx` ;) Will this be useful? :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @HarishKumar Does that qualify as 'lesser-known'?

Comment: @cfr I am not sure :)